# Avoid Branch Divergence in CUDA String Searching

Tags: c, search, cuda, gpu

I would like to know how to avoid branch divergence in string searching with CUDA, and if there was a good way to do it.

At the moment I tried to adapt Knuth Morris Pratt to GPUs but I believe that there is a lot of divergence since each thread is looking for N letters and comparing each time if this letters correspond to the first letter of the word I'm searching.

```
int tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
int startId = tid * 64;
int x = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++){
    if(array[startId + i] == 'C'){
        x++;
    }
}
```

if I use this dummy code to find the letter 'C', but I could also make a second look to search for more letters as well.

Comment: @Anoracx: Your link only contains a simple serial implementation. What about your GPU code?

Comment: It was not my code, I just tried to implement that one on a GPU.

Comment: @Anoracx What if you replicate your array of letters to become a matrix of letters and then each thread reads each column and compares to the `desiredLetter`?

Comment: @KiaMorot but you still face a problem if you want to compare to more than one letter, or against a string.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the results of the comparisions directly into the value like so:

x+= (array[startId + i] == 'C');

But that I believe this may still branch. My solution would be to store array values in a block to shared memory and then assign each thread in the block a desired character and place the results into their own shared memory space then reduce.

```
__shared__ char l_array[BLOCK_SIZE];
__shared__ char l_results[BLOCK_SIZE];

int bid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
int lid = threadIdx.x;
int tid = bid + lid;
int x=0;

char desired_char = get_character(lid);


l_array[lid] = -1;


//Store global values in shared memory
if(tid < array_size){
    l_array[lid] = array[tid];       
}

__syncthreads();

//Check local memory for desired character
for(int i = 0; i < BLOCK_SIZE; i++)
   x+=(l_array[i] == desired_char);

//Store results into shared memory
l_results[lid] = x;

__syncthreads();
//Then reduce (poorly)
if(lid==0){
    for(int i = 0; i < BLOCK_SIZE; i++)
        x+= l_results[i];
}
```

Although i don't know the algorithm per se, I'm just guessing but something along the lines here might help you figure this out.